# Suppress now printing dialog - Microsoft VBS

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, printing

**Context**:
I'm trying to create a task in Windows to automatically print a file at certain hour of the day whether the user is logged on or not.

I've read on the web that in order to execute a task this way the program or script most be completely silent.

I was able to open a excel file and execute the macro completely silently but at the very end there is a dialog of windows that says:

This is the Excel macro i use to print the document

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()

   'To print use:
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").PrintOut 1, 1, 1, False

End Sub
```

"Now printing ...."

**Question**
How can i suppress that dialog?

This is the VBS script i'm currently using:

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample()

  Dim xlApp
  Dim xlBook

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Public\test.xlsm", 0, False)
  xlApp.Run "Auto_Open"
  xlApp.Quit

  Set xlBook = Nothing
  Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I tried changing options of the Open function between False and True but it was the same.

Comment: So you have another macro that is run? Can you share that or a portion also?

Comment: I think APIs are your only hope ad the print dialog is an internal function. See http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0037.htm for use.

Comment: I added the code @glh

Comment: @glh that website says `The Printing dialog is an internal Access dialog, and as such, cannot be hidden directly from code` So there is no hope? i need the dialog to not open at all